# How to customize the request from HTML to Servlet

Tags: java, html, servlets, httprequest

I am building a server using Java's servlet and HTML forms.

I already managed to upload files: the user reach an HTML page, chose the file he/she wants to upload in his/her tree folder. The file is sent to a servlet I've written and downloaded on the server (actually I'm only running it on localhost for the moment, so the server is my 'My Documents' folder).

The next step I would like to make is this one:
The user (once logged, but I will manage to do that) reaches an HTML page, select a file that is hosted by the server and download it.

To make it, I will have to send to the 'Download Servlet' the name of the file. So here are my questions:

- How to list the files that are in 'My Documents' on the HTML page.
- How to send the name of the selected file to the servlet.
- How to catch the 'request' and make a String of the name out of it.

To precise these two lasts points, please have a look at this:

```
List<FileItem> items = null;
items = upload.parseRequest(request);
FileItem item = items.get(0);
String fileName = item.getName();
```

The block above catches the name of the folder that is in the request. What I actually want to do is to do the same thing if what is in the request is a String (=catch the String contained in the request).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `File` API will give you what you need for selecting the files in your directory.

```
List<File> files = Arrays.asList(new File("/your/directory").listFiles());

List<String> fileNames = new LinkedList<>();
for (File file : files) {
    fileNames.add(somePrefix + file.getName());
}

request.setAttribute("fileNames", fileNames);
```

I do the above because you might not want to give the real path to your files, for security reasons. Once you have the list of file names in your request attributes, you can iterate over them in a jsp.

```
<form ...>
    Select a file:<br />
    <c:forEach items="${fileNames}" var="fileName">
        <input type="radio" name="fileName" value="${fileName}">
    </c:forEach>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Submit
</form>
```

Now the files are each attached to an input element, which will translate to a request parameter. When the form is submitted, you can access the select file name by doing

```
String fileName = request.getParameter("fileName");
```

You can then append that file name to some directory structure and go and find it on the file system.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !

So your way is to establish the list of names in a servlet, send it to an HTML page that is going to print it.
I understood that the user is able to select the file with a radio button (which is exactly what I was looking for !).
But if I got it all, this way will add one step in the navigation, isn't it ?
It would go this way:

HTML (home page) => servlet (set the files names list) => HTML (radio button) => servlet (download the file).

If so, do you know how I could send the fileNames list from the second servlet to the HTML page with the radio button ?
Thanks !

Comment: @user2712309 Say the servlet is at `/files`. You do an HTTP GET to `/files`. The servlet is executed and the corresponding HTML is rendered and sent in the HTTP response, which is what you see in the browser. The user selects a radio button and clicks submit. The browser will send a new HTTP request containing a request parameter for the selected button (to whatever `action` attribute you set in the `form`). Your download servlet is hit and sends back the bytes for the selected file.

Comment: Great !
I'm a beginner in that kind of development and I didn't even know that a HTTP request to /files would be possible.
Thank you once again for your help, I will do it this way !
Max.